# ODBC connect, get a table in R

Tags: sql, r, odbc, r-dbi

Wrestling the whole day with this issue:

I Want to access data on Hadoop (through Hive). And installed the ODBC package.

I'm able to make connection with the server:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc:: odbc(), "hadoop")
```

And I am able to see the table that I want to get in R:

```
dblistTables(con, schema= "aacs")
```

The output is:

```
   [1] "dev_1"                  "dev_2"     
   [3] "dev_3"                  "dev_4"
```

I want to have "dev_4" (in a data frame) in my R environment. I tried:

```
db_orders <- tbl(con, "dev_4")
```

But I got an error: Table or view not found. Also the next line lead to nothing.

```
db_orders <- tbl(con, "aacs.dev_4")
```

How can I get that data table in my R environment?

**EDIT 1**

Tried to run the next two things:

```
result <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM aacs.dev_4")
```

Received an error: No Space left on device.

Ok, so let's reduce the query then:

```
result <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM aacs.dev_4 LIMIT 100")
```

But again, the same error:

```
Error: <SQL> 'SELECT * FROM aacs.dev_4 limit 100'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: HY000: [Hortonworks][Hardy] (35) Error from server: error code: '2' error message: 'Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_15177720341_0081_2_08, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_15177723341_0081_2_08_000146, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: FS Error in Child JVM:org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSError: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.write(RawLocalFileSystem.java:261)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:58)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.IFileOutputStream.write(IFil
```

Anyone an idea how to solve this? It is strange that there is no memory left.. because I have a lot of space (enough to store the data!).

**EDIT 2**

As @Florian suggested:

```
data <- dbReadTable(con, "aacs.dev_4")
```

Led to the next error:

```
Error: <SQL> 'SELECT * FROM `aacs.dev_4`'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: HY000: [Hortonworks][Hardy] (35) Error from server: error code: '2' error message: 'Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1517772023341_0082_1_08, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1517772023341_0082_1_08_000236, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: exceptionThrown=org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in fetcher {Map_4} #10
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:360)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:337)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
x <- dbReadTable(con, "dev_4")
```

Full working example:

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

dbListTables(con)
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars)
x <- dbReadTable(con, "mtcars")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Florian, this is what I got if I run it: 

Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:144: 42S02: [Hortonworks][SQLEngine] (3740) Table or view not found: HIVE..dev_4

Comment: Could it be the case, that it is because we have Hadoop, than a "folder" (aacs) and in that folder, there is the "dev_4"...

EDIT: Not the case, when I print: dbListTables(con), I see the "dev_4"

Answer (score 0):

I know what went wrong...

There is an error in the View ("dev_4"). Because when I ran the code:

```
test <- dbReadTable(con, "dev_3")
```

I got the data frame returned. Time to connect with the Data engineer... thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
data<- dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT * FROM aacs.dev_4 LIMIT 100")
```